# Etimología de "caló"

Tags: etimología, historia, caló

**Caló** aparece definido en distintos diccionarios, desde el de Castro y Rossi [1852]:

> Dialecto carcelero o gitanesco.

como en los de la RAE:

> - Jerga que hablan los **rufianes** y gitanos. `[1884]`
> - Lenguaje o dialecto de los gitanos. `[1914]`
> - Lenguaje o dialecto de los gitanos **adoptado en parte por la gente del pueblo bajo**. `[1925 - 1956]`
> - Lenguaje o dialecto de los gitanos. `[1970 - 1983]`
> - Lenguaje de los gitanos **españoles**. `[1989, 1992]`

hasta el actual [caló](http://dle.rae.es/?id=6qTMDHZ)

> 1. adj. Perteneciente o relativo al caló. *Léxico caló.*
> 2. m. Variedad del romaní que hablan los gitanos **de España, Francia y Portugal**.

En ninguna de las entradas de los diccionarios se hace una referencia a la etimología de la palabra, salvo en la [edición actual](http://dle.rae.es/?id=6qTMDHZ):

> Del caló *caló* 'negro'.

que es una etimología que me parece llamativa: que se aplique para designar a la lengua una palabra que en esa lengua significa **negro**.

No he encontrado ninguna etimología en el "Diccionario general etimologico de la lengua española" de Dios Echegaray, y ni siquiera aparece la palabra *caló* en el "Diccionario de argot español o lenguaje jergal" de Luis Besses.

En el Diccionario de Corominas se indica escuetamente "Del gitano *caló* 'gitano', que parece tener más lógica que lo recogido por la RAE.

¿Hay alguna otra etimología? ¿Por qué la RAE indica esa extraña etimología frente a la de Corominas, tras más de un siglo sin recoger ninguna?

Comment: Has visto el articulo de wikipedia? https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idioma_caló

Answer (score 3):

No hay una oposición: puede ser que *caló* viene últimamente de *caló* "negro" **vía** la otra significación de *caló* ("gitano").

Wikipedia nos ofrece esta hipótesis, que el endónimo del pueblo viene del color:

> #### [Etymology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cal%C3%B3_language#Etymology)
>
> *Calé* is the endonym of the Romani people in Iberia, and *caló* means "the language spoken by the *calé*". However, the *calé* are commonly known in Portuguese- and Spanish-speaking countries by the exonyms *ciganos* and *gitanos*.
>
> In *caló* and other varieties of Romani, *kalo* means "black"... hence closely resembling words for "black" and/or "dark" in Indo-Aryan languages (e.g. Sanskrit काल *kāla* "black", "of a dark colour"). **Hence *caló* and *calé* may have originated as ancient exonyms. For instance, the name of the Domba people,** whom the Romani, Sinti and Kale people are now believed to havex emerged,<sup>[7]</sup> **also implies "dark-skinned" in some Indian languages.**<sup>[8]</sup>
>
> ...
>
> <sup>7.  [*The Phylogeography of Y-Chromosome Haplogroup H1a1a-M82 Reveals the Likely Indian Origin of the European Romani Populations*](http://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0048477), N. Rai et al. (2012)</sup>
>
> <sup>8. *Bury Me Standing: The Gypsies and their Journey*, Isabel Fonseca (p.100)</sup>

---

Más información sobre las entradas de la RAE:

- [*El léxico gitano en la lexicografía española*](https://digilib.phil.muni.cz/bitstream/handle/11222.digilib/124078/SpisyFF_389-2010-1_8.pdf) (5.26 calé, 5.27 caló)

Y términos afines en caló:

> **CALÓ, LLÍ.**
>   adj. Atezado, moreno, a. || A SUETÍ CALLÍ; el pueblo gitano.

> **CALORRÓ, Í.**
>   s. Gitano, a (moderno, en oposicion á ZINCALÓ, gitano primitivo). || E BATÍ ON BATÍ ABILLELO SINANDO CALORRÓ; de generacion en generacion vengo siendo gitano.

> **ZINCALÓ, LLÍ.**
>   s. Gitano, a. (Más propiamente *gitano primitivo.*) || CALORRÓS ACHIBÉ NA CHIBAN DRAO ON AS BRAJÍAS, SATA ZINCALÉS YE CHIRÓ PURÓ; los gitanos hoy dia no envenenan los ganados como los gitanos de los antiguos tiempos.

- [*Diccionario gitano*](https://es.wikisource.org/wiki/Diccionario_gitano/Vocabulario_cal%C3%B3-castellano), Francisco Quindalé